# How do I set the drop down list on my manipulate function to show variables instead of numeric values?

Tags: manipulate

This is the code. When executed, it produces the graph I want but the drop down list only shows numeric values instead of the variables assigned to those values (instead of HCl on the list it shows 2.955247074531915`*^29). How do I have it so the drop down list shows the list of molecules, not the values they are set equal to?

```
Manipulate[Plot[{10^10 (x - (1/(2 Pi*c) (molecule)^(1/2))
 )}, {x, 0, 6000}, PlotRange -> {0, 10}, 
{molecule, {H2,D2, HBr, HI, HCl, Cl2, Br2, I2, 
   O2, N2, CO, NO, Na2, NaCl, KCl}}]  
{H2 = 6.872328008374696`*^29, D2 = 3.172075526392709`*^29, 
HCl = 2.955247074531915`*^29, HBr = 2.4542151887009904`*^29, 
HI = 1.7644561453673114`*^29, Cl2 = 1.0889819266656353`*^28, 
Br2 = 3.701742347323016`*^27, I2 = 1.609757100669017`*^27, 
O2 = 8.590537300106641`*^28, N2 = 1.9262514765196563`*^29, 
CO = 1.629466681480819`*^29, NO = 1.2487250117754684`*^29, 
Na2 = 8.857584751945457`*^26, NaCl = 5.069728968502544`*^27, 
KCl = 2.742147011574077`*^27};
c = 29979245800;
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 5):

One way to do it would be using the syntax:

```
PopupMenu[x,{val1->"name1",val2->"name2",...}]
```

My code looks like this:

```
c = 29979245800;
PopupMenu[
 Dynamic[molecule], {6.872328008374696`*^29 -> "H2", 
  3.172075526392709`*^29 -> "D2", 2.955247074531915`*^29 -> "HCl", 
  2.4542151887009904`*^29 -> "HBr", 1.7644561453673114`*^29 -> "HI", 
  1.0889819266656353`*^28 -> "Cl2", 3.701742347323016`*^27 -> "Br2", 
  1.609757100669017`*^27 -> "I2", 8.590537300106641`*^28 -> "O2", 
  1.9262514765196563`*^29 -> "N2", 1.629466681480819`*^29 -> "CO", 
  1.2487250117754684`*^29 -> "NO", 8.857584751945457`*^26 -> "Na2", 
  5.069728968502544`*^27 -> "NaCl", 2.742147011574077`*^27 -> "KCl"}]
Manipulate[
 Plot[{10^10 (x - (1/(2 Pi*c) (molecule)^(1/2)))}, {x, 0, 6000}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 10}], Dynamic[molecule]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for that! I used the syntax you have (6.872328008374696`*^29 -> "H2") in my code and it worked!